How can I get serde to emit the fields that failed to parse in the error output?
I have a date field that is failing to parse. Serde isn't telling me which field is failing, which is problematic, because this field is actually many layers deep in my real JSON payload, and took a bit of binary searching to figure out that that it was infact the date field that was actually failing.
In other words, serde failure isn't telling me which field is failing to parse in valid JSON. How can I make it do so?
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8d9e8f8d97626916873b10a3ea780449

If you recognize the errors, then it kind of is telling where it's from. It's a chrono error. Since "2024-1-1" is a Date and not a DateTime, thus parsing it as a DateTime results in a premature end of input error. There's various ways to work around it. Overall if you want more descriptive errors, then you need to use deserialize_with and then map_err() into custom more descriptive errors

Actually it's completely telling you where the error comes from. In your playground that's line 1, column  19, i.e. at the end of the "2024-1-1" string.

@jmb, it's clear where it comes from here because created a MVP repo. The actual payload in question was easily 5 levels deep with 100+ fields. My ask isn't "why is this failing" it's "how can I get serde to tell me which field failed to parse".

This has nothing to do with it being an MRE and everything to do with the serde error message: "Error("premature end of input", line: 1, column: 19)". In your real payload, you might get huge line/column numbers, but any halfway decent text editor is able to jump to a given position and show you not only the field that caused the error, but the actual character where it failed.

In our case, the line/col were always the end of the full, top-level payload. The line/column were not reliably reporting in the real collection of structs.

You can use serde_path_to_error to add location information to any deserialization error.
(I haven't used it myself, but I've seen it recommended and it is written by the same author as serde itself, David Tolnay.)

This seems like a good solution. Thanks for the link!
